# IOS Safari iframe session

Tags: session, iframe, safari

We have a script that the customer can use to inject another script and an iframe into it's page to show a checkout popup. It works fine everywhere but on Safari mobile where we run into problem with cookies inside iframe.
It works when the visitor visits our site first, because it sets the cookies, and then they are available to iframe too. But we can't expect that situation, so we devised a cunning plan to quickly open a popup window to our site in the background that would serve as a session & cookies starter and as soon as the headers are sent would be closed. Enter popup blocker...

I would just like to know if it's possible to have an iframe checkout on Safari or not?